# Help on understanding the particular integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help with trying to understand the solution to $\operatorname{y}'' + \operatorname{y} = 5x{\rm e}^{2x}$:

- Clearly the auxillary equation is just $m^2 + 1 = 0$ which can be solved by $m= \pm {\rm i}$, thereby giving us $A\cos\left(x\right) + B\sin\left(x\right)$ for our complementary function.
- The issue comes with the particular integral, so far, I have been taught to use the "most general form of the $RHS$" and "multiply by $x$ if the expected particular integral contains any term from the complementary function".
- Clearly the particular integral and the complementary function do not share any terms, therefore I would say the most general form of the $RHS$ is simply $\mu x{\rm e}^{2x}$, however it turns out that I should have used $\mu x{\rm e}^{2x} + \lambda {\rm e}^{2x}$, could someone explain this please $?$.

Thanks !!.

Comment: There isn't too much to explain. Your RHS was a linear times $e^{2x},$ so your P.I. initial guess 
should be the most general form of  a linear times $e^{2x},$ If the RHS was a quadratic, then your P.I. initial guess should be a general quadratic multiplied by $e^{2x}.$ And so on. If you're asking, "why does this all work?", or "why should we choose those to be our P.I.'s in those cases?", then I don't know why that is.

Comment: The "most general form of the RHS" means: if there is a polynomial in the RHS (like $5x$ here), take a *polynomial* of the same degree (not a monomial). So here: $\mu x+\lambda$ (not just $\mu x$).

Comment: I can see that now! Is there a website providing any proofs as to why all this works? Thanks.

Comment: [Here](https://fr.wikiversity.org/wiki/%C3%89quation_diff%C3%A9rentielle/%C3%89quation_diff%C3%A9rentielle_lin%C3%A9aire_du_deuxi%C3%A8me_ordre_%C3%A0_coefficients_constants#Cas_particulier_o%C3%B9_%7F'%22%60UNIQ--postMath-00000055-QINU%60%22'%7F) is a proof (in French). Note that if the "expected particular integral" contains an exponential $e^{rx}$ where $r$ is a *double* root of the characteristic equation, then you will have to multiply not by $x$ but by $x^2$.

Comment: Merci Beaucoup!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\on{y}''\pars{x} + \on{y}\pars{x} = 5x\expo{2x}}:\ {\LARGE ?}.\ \mbox{Lets}\ \on{z}\pars{x} \equiv \on{y}'\pars{x} + \on{y}\pars{x}\ic
\\[5mm] &  \mbox{such that}\
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\on{y}''\pars{x} + \on{y}\pars{x}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\on{z}'\pars{x} - \on{z}\pars{x}\ic}
\\[1mm]
\ds{\on{y}\pars{x}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\Im\on{z}\pars{x}}
\\[1mm]
\ds{\on{y}'\pars{x}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\Re\on{z}\pars{x}}
\end{array}\right.
\\[5mm] & \mbox{Then,}\ \on{z}'\pars{x} - \on{z}\pars{x}\ic = 5x\expo{2x}
\\[2mm] & \implies
\expo{-x\ic}\on{z}'\pars{x} -
\expo{-x\ic}\on{z}\pars{x}\ic = 5x\expo{2x}\expo{-x\ic}
\\[2mm] & \implies
\totald{\bracks{\expo{-x\ic}\on{z}\pars{x}}}{x} = 5x\expo{\pars{2 - \ic}x}
\\[2mm] & \implies
\expo{-x\ic}\on{z}\pars{x} =
5\int x\expo{\pars{2 - \ic}x}\,\dd x + a,\quad
a \in \mathbb{C}= \mbox{constant}
\\[2mm] & \implies
\bbx{\color{#44f}{\on{z}\pars{x} =
\bracks{-\,{3 + 4\ic \over 5} + \pars{2 + \ic}x}\expo{2x} + a\expo{x\ic}}}
\\[2mm] &\mbox{The value of}\ a\
\mbox{is determined by the boundary conditions.}
\end{align}